# Is $\left\langle n\mathbb{Z}, + \right\rangle$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

show that $\left\langle n\mathbb{Z}, + \right\rangle$ is a group where $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\mathbb{Z}$ := {$nm$ : $m \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$} ($+$ is the "usual" integer addition we are used to).

I am working on the following example and confused by the following solution when showing that $\forall$ $a \in n\mathbb{Z}$, $a^-1 \in n\mathbb{Z}$ (proving there exist an inverse for all $a$):

[image]

won't $0$ not have an inverse? (assuming since $m=0$)

Comment: Surely $n\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$? As the operation is addition, the inverse of $0$ will be $0$ (the inverse of the identity is always the identity).

Comment: @Dzoooks what are you talking about "*The identity doesn't have an inverse.*"  This is incorrect.  The correct statement is "The identity doesn't have an inverse *which is different than itself*" but notice that the identity is its own inverse.  It isn't that the inverse of the identity doesn't exist, it is just that it isn't different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero is its own inverse.
$$0 + (-0) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Identity element and elements of order 2 are self inverse.

Answer (score 1):

The identity is its own inverse, as always.

And, in general, $x^{-1}=-x$, as $x+(-x)=0$.